# scrapy spider download images on my laptop and doesn't on another laptop

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have a problem with Scrapy it is downloading images just fine on my laptop but when I send the client the code it is only scraping the data not downloading the pictures.
Can you help me with it?

here is the code

### settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'project_mohie.pipelines.customImagePipline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'local_folder'
```

### pipelines.py

```
class customImagePipline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        return f"{item['EAN Code']}_{item['image_urls'].index(request.url)}.jpg"
```

### items.py

```
class ProjectMohieItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    images=scrapy.Field()
```

The client uses python 3.7.3 because he has windows 7 running.
I tried everything it works fine on my laptop
I even tried to add it in the custom settings like that but doesn't work

```
custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'data.csv': {
            'format': 'csv',
            'encoding': 'utf-8-sig',
            'store_empty': False,
            'fields': None,
            'indent': 4,
            'item_export_kwargs': {'export_empty_fields': True,},
        }
    },
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
        "IMAGES_STORE" :'local_folder'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure why it's not working on your clients' device. Currently I am using the following snippets to retrieve all images from the scraped webpages:

## settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.customImagePipeline': 1
}
IMAGES_STORE = 'local_img_folder'
```

## pipelines.py

```
class customImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        return request.url.split('/')[-1]
```

## items.py

```
class ScrapingImagesItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

## myspider.py

```
# Images
raw_image_urls = response.css('img::attr(src)').getall() 
clean_image_urls=[]
for img_url in raw_image_urls:
    clean_image_urls.append(response.urljoin(img_url))

yield {
    'image_urls': clean_image_urls
}
```

This way the pictures are stored locally in the folder 'local_img_folder', and have their original file names.
I hope this helps for your project too :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing I'm gonna try it in my laptop and test it on my client's laptop
again thanks for sharing

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I just did try on my client's laptop 
still not downloading any images 
I can't find a suitable reason why it is happening